# Node Package loading

Tags: javascript, node.js

I freshly started with Node and have some issues with my package. I make an MVC system for Electron, so it's a library. To make it a public module, I made another project and added my local installation as dependency.

The issue is, I can't require/load my package. I tried various ways, but I don't really seem to get it. Currently that's my code (Inspired from the Electron API loading):

```
// lib/index.js
...
module.exports = require('./exports/cord')
...

// lib/exports/cord.js
'use strict'

module.exports = {
  cord: require('../cord'),
  controller: require('../controller')
}
```

While the ***lib/cord.js*** and ***lib/controller.js*** contain the main code, the *l**ib/exports/cord.js*** should expose these to the public if I got it right.
However, when I try to use it in the other project like this:

```
const {cord, controller} = require("cord");
```

or any other way with require, it gives me this error:

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'cord'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dominik/Documents/workspace/ShowType/app.js:2:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
```

Comment: if cord is your custom class. you have to give the correct file path. It wil not load direcly .. check the path inside require(''); Add ../ if u want to move one folder up\

Comment: I know the basics. The module is a package and is installed via NPM in the node_modules folder. Therefore it should be able to load the package by just 'cord', since that one already exposes the Module to the public with the ***lib/exports/cord.js*** File. And that one has the proper locations in it.

Comment: make `cord` a file path and it'll work. Or publish it as a npm module

Comment: Published the Package to NPM to test it and it doesn't workl. Same issue.